# NullPointerException on initialized object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm working on my first android app, and I'm trying to add a `spinner` to my view. By looking at the Android Developers Guide, I figured out how to add it to my view, and how to actually add items to the spinner.

Except for when I actually try to add items and the following pops up:

`Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference`

As you can see I'm trying to run `.setAdapter()` on a spinner object. Normally this error would occur if I would try this without initializing the spinner object, but I did:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.where_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.where_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code above is all called after I call `setContentView()` so that's not the problem.

How can it be that something as simple as a spinner is causing me so much trouble?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After I saw a particular comment, I saw that I forgot to add that the layout file that contains `where_spinner` is the layout used for a dialog. The `where_spinner` should be accessible though, since any other objects in that layout also are.

Comment: `findViewById` can return `null`

Comment: `spinner` is null. Does the layout you set with `setContentView()` really have `where_spinner`, or is it in e.g. a fragment layout?

Comment: @laalto It does, and it doesn't. I forgot to mention that the `where_spinner` is in a layout file used for a dialog, but since I can do this with other elements in that same layout, I thought it wouldn't really matter much

Comment: So it seems you need to be calling `findViewById()` on your dialog's view hierarchy and not your activity's as you're doing now.

Comment: @laalto Fun fact: I did this on a button object but not on the spinner. *facepalm* Would you post this as an answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `spinner` is `null`. `Activity#findViewById()` returns nulls if the view is not found in the activity's view hierarchy you've set with `setContentView()`, or `setContentView()` has not been called at all.

Based on the comments your `where_spinner` is in fact in a dialog view hierarchy. Call `findViewById()` on the dialog's hierarchy and not on the activity to find it.